# Laravel SOAP request - 419 unknown status

Tags: laravel, soap, payment

I'm making a request to a `SOAP service` from a Laravel application. This service requests a `redirectUrl` field when I send the request to let me know if the operation was successful. It is sending a POST request to the redirectURL field. When it sends I get error 419 unknown status. How can I solve this problem? Do I need to make any changes on the server side? I have a server based on Ubuntu and Nginx?

[image: request]

I want to get past error 419 unknown status. I don't want to receive 419 when the service I sent sends me a POST request.

Answer (score 0):

As it request outside of Laravel, you need to add this route to `$except` array of `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware, see docs: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/csrf#csrf-excluding-uris